# How to make Single Product URL

Tags: store-view, product-view, seo, magento-2.2.5, product-urls

Magento Version: EE 2.2.5

In my store product detail page is accessible using three urls:

1) https://www.domain-name.com/L1category/L2category/test-product

2) https://www.domain-name.com/test-product

3) https://www.domain-name.com/catalog/product/view/id/7862

But I need the product url to be a single one (https://www.domain-name.com/L1category/L2category/test-product)

And I can't use url rewrites as there are too many products.

Is there any other way?

Comment: If you are assigning the product to multiple categories then magento will generate multiple urls. But you can do one thing for frontend. Disable Use category path in Product url from admin.

Comment: I'm not assigning a product to n categories, even if so then n urls have to be generated not nx3. If I disable the Use category path in Product url from admin then it will be https://www.domain-name.com/test-product but i need as https://www.domain-name.com/L1category/L2category/test-product